# Remove unstrusted token from ERC20 Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I have a question and I try to google without much existence.

Let's take the example of this token:
[1inch Token](https://etherscan.io/address/0x111111111117dc0aa78b770fa6a738034120c302)

So you can see that it has different tokens that people have sent to that address.

If I were the owner, how could I implement a function to withdraw all those tokens to my wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your contract can define the `ERC20` interface function `transfer()`, and then execute this function on the external token contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface IERC20 {
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract MyContract {
    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == address(0x123), 'Not authorized');
        _;
    }

    function withdrawERC20Token(address _tokenContractAddress, uint256 _amount) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(_tokenContractAddress);
        
        // transfer the `_amount` of tokens (mind the decimals) from this contract address
        // to the `msg.sender` - the caller of the `withdrawERC20Token()` function
        bool success = token.transfer(msg.sender, _amount);
        require(success, 'Could not withdraw');
    }
}
```